# Documentation in webpack template for installed in buildfiresdk

Tags: javascript, webpack, buildfire

I am trying to create a app with the buildfiresdk.  I generated a buildfire plugin using the "buildfire plugin init  webpack" command, however I am not sure how to edit this template to make it my own.  Could anyone point me to a documentation that helps with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should see 2 folders on the root of the plugin folder:

- webpack: Responsible for all your webpack settings. You may not need to change anything.
- src: This is where all your plugin source code is at. You will be making the majority of your changes here.

**This template has some dependencies.** So you want to navigate through the CLI to the root of the plugin and then execute `npm install` this will then install all that is needed.

Once the dependencies are installed. You can now **run webpack to auto bundle changes** for you on the fly by executing `npm start` at the root of the plugin.

You should be ready to start the SDK now. Simply open a **separate terminal window.** Then navigate to the root of the SDK and execute `buildfire run`

You should be good to go.